# MS Access 2010 Set up Row source for form with parameterf from another element

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a database that has the following tables in Access 2010:

```
TblServices [ServiceCountry,ServiceName]

TblServiceCountry [CountryID,CountryName]

TblServiceList[ListID,ListName,ListCountry]
```

- ServiceCountry is a combobox with values from the TblServiceCountry.
- ServiceName is a combobox with values from the TblServiceList
- ListCountry is a combobox with values from the TblServiceCountry.
- ListCountry is not a required field.

I have tried multiple queries in a form made from tblServices to get the row Source for Servicename to take only the ListName that has the ListCountry Null OR ListCountry=ServiceCountry of that record but with no luck.

> SQL Query:`Select DISTINCT ListID, ListName From ServiceList, Services Where (IsNull(ListCountry)<>False AND (IsNull(ListCountry)<>False OR ListCountry=ServiceCountry);`

Ex:
ServiceList:

```
ListID | ListName         | ListCountry
1      |   Tax Service    | NULL 
2      |   Clean Service  | Italy
3      |   Food Service   | USA
```

- If ServiceCountry = Italy then only 1 and 2 ListName should show up.
- If ServiceCountry = USA then only 1 and 3 ListName should show up
- If ServiceCountry = Brazil then only 1 ListName should show up.

I'm new in Access so any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Edit your question to post the relevant RowSource SQL statements as well as VBA code.

Comment: Thank you! I have edited the post. There is no VBA code as I have tried but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should only need the OR operation and only TblServiceList. Suggest naming combobox for ServiceCountry different from field, like cbxCountry.

TblServiceList is saving the actual descriptive text of service and country, not IDs? Don't really have word NULL in field? If you want to save descriptive text of ListName, the ListID is not needed. If you want to save ListID then DISTINCT is meaningless.

Try:

`Select DISTINCT ListName From TblServiceList Where ListCountry Is Null OR ListCountry LIKE [cbxCountry] & "*";`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! The country conboboxes save the ID as they are use on other queries.

Comment: If the value of cbxCountry is CountryID then the wildcard will not work properly.